# onDataChange unexpected behavior

Tags: android, firebase

I have the following code, on `FirstActivity.java`:

```
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (data == 0) {                
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } 
}
```

and on `SecondActivity.java`, I update the `data` value, and it starts the `ThirdActivity` immediately on update, although I never call to start this activity in the `SecondActivity`  and I suspect it's due to the fact that it's happening on `FirstActivity.java` (It's the only place I redirect to that activity). But I call `finish()`, then how come this `onDataChange` is triggered from another activity? is it because of `getApplicationContext()` maybe? how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

When you're listening for "realtime updates" in Firebase, a "Listener" is assigned.  This listener is a registration for the call to "listen" for changes.  You have to manage this manually and detach or remove the listener when you are finished.

[This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) is the Firebase Documentation for managing listeners.

This is the just of one of the examples:

```
Query query = db.collection("cities");
ListenerRegistration registration = query.addSnapshotListener(
    new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
      // ...
    });

// ...

// Stop listening to changes
registration.remove();
```

Your suspicion is correct, even though you call `finish()` the listener is still registered to listen. So you just need to grab the listener when you initially make the call and then "remove" it before moving on to the next activity.

---

### Edit with my example

I have a document change listener in my app.  So in my activity I assign the listener variable at the Activity level:

```
public class AMainScreen extends FragmentActivity {

...

private ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration;

...

}
```

Then I call to listen to a document and assign the listner:

```
listenerRegistration = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(collectionName).document(documentId).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                /// handle error
            } else {
                if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.getData() != null) {
                    /// handle document snapshot
                } else {
                    /// handle docSnapshot null
                }
            }
        }
     }));
```

Then you just call `remove()` on the listener when you're done:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (listenerRegistration != null) {
        listenerRegistration.remove();
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: But you see in my code, I move to the next activity from within the listener, then how can I cancel that listener? in the `onDestroy()` method of the activity?

Comment: So you can create an `Activity` level variable for the listener and assign it when you initially make the call.  Then just call `remove()` on it from inside the `OnDataChanged` callback where your `finish()` call is located.

Comment: I get errors when I try, cannot resolve. Could you help me with the code please?

Comment: I cannot remove the event listener from itself, then where should I do it? I think on Desotry

Comment: @Stackpile I added my example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly using the method addValueEventListener (), this method is a listener in the background, for example if you referenced it to a route in your RealTimeDatabase, it will keep listening until you remove the listener, if on the other hand you only need to launch a query once I recommend using addListenerForSingleValueEvent ().

Here you will find all the required documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write